# How to do arithmetic with timestamps and intervals in Rust Diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I've been trying to construct a diesel query with filter expressions that do arithmetic and comparison on timestamps and time intervals. I believe the following expressions are not possible to write using out-of-the-box diesel. Unfortunately, I've resorted to the sledgehammer approach of using the `sql(...)` function:

```rust
let query = videos::table
    .inner_join(events::table)
    .filter(sql(r#""events"."start_date" <= NOW() + interval '60 seconds'"#))
    .filter(sql(r#""events"."start_date" + ("videos"."duration" * interval '1 second') > NOW()"#))
```

My (abbreviated) schema:

```rust
table! {
    events (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        video_id -> Int4,
        start_date -> Timestamp,
    }
}

table! {
    videos (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        duration -> Float4,
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. Am I wrong? Can this be written in diesel with no custom types?
2. If this cannot be written in vanilla diesel, how can I break this up into a more type-safe, diesel-friendly expression? Which parts are custom and what traits do I need to implement?

Comment: what stop you from using the way to filter like https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/ ?

Comment: @Stargateur I have plenty of normal diesel filters throughout the rest of my app, but I don't know how to make a filter that does arithmetic on timestamps and intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I wrong? Can this be written in diesel with no custom types?

Yes this can be written with methods provided by diesel and some minor schema changes. See the corresponding [documentation](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/expression/extensions/trait.IntervalDsl.html)

Diesel requires that you only can add/substract intervals to timestamps. That implies that you need your schema a little bit to make this possible:

```rust
table! {
    videos (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        duration -> Interval,
    }
}
```

Your query then is written like this:

```rust
let query = videos::table
    .inner_join(events::table)
    .filter(events::start_date.le(now + 60.seconds()))
    .filter(now.lt(events::start_date + videos::duration))
```

> If this cannot be written in vanilla diesel, how can I break this up into a more type-safe, diesel-friendly expression? Which parts are custom and what traits do I need to implement?

In theory it should be possible to implement that outside of diesel. The code would be very likely the same that is used to implement that in diesel itself. Probably you would need to use local types and more concrete impls. So if you cannot change the type of `videos::duration` it may be meaningful to go down this route.

Comment: Oh wow, this looks great. I will try later today and report back, thanks!

Comment: The first filter works perfectly, but the compiler is complaining about the second one. I think this part: `videos::duration * 1.second()`. Maybe I'm not importing something correctly? Error is: `the trait \`diesel::Expression\` is not implemented for \`diesel::data_types::PgInterval\``

Comment: You are right, the second filter does not work that way I've initially written. The problem there is that diesel says you cannot add arbitrary numbers with timestamps. You can only do that with intervals. The simplest fix here would be to change the type of `videos::duration` to `Interval` instead of `Float4`. I've edited the answer accordingly.